# JQuery simple form submit - get data, calculate average, display to user

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple form that works with jQuery. I have made some sort of mistake. Can someone help me understand what I did wrong?

Here is the link to JS Bin snippet : **https://jsbin.com/tafubuq/edit?html,console,output**

For reference, the code is below:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <h1>Learning functions and forms</h1>
  <form id="make-average">
  <label for="average">Give me first number</label>
  <input type="text" name="user-entry" id="user-entry-1" placeholder="e.g., 3">
  <label for="average">Give me second number</label>
  <input type="text" name="user-entry" id="user-entry-2" placeholder="e.g., 3">
  <input type="submit" id="additems">
  <br><br>
  <div id="show-result">  </div>
</body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
```

**JS:**

```
function makeAverage(firstNubmer, secondNumber) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#make-average").submit(function() {
    var firstNumber = $("#user-entry-1").val();
    var secondNumber = $("#user-entry-2").val();
    var average = (firstNumber + secondNumber) / 2;
    return average;
  });
}

function displayAverage() {
  $("#show-result").html(average);
}

makeAverage(firstNumber, secondNumber);
displayAverage();
```

Comment: from your jsbin: you're using jquery sintaxe but jquery import is being loaded after the script you've created (use `document.ready` sintaxe. You're calling `makeAverage(firstNumber, secondNumber);` when `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` don't exist (the call should be something like `makeAverage(10, 5);`)...to finish: you're using `event.preventDefault()` when you don't even have an `event`

Comment: You have arguments `firstNumber,secondNumber` (typos asside) but then overwrite these by getting the values from the DOM.  There's no need to have these as parameters if you get them within the function.

Comment: You also return the average from the `submit()` handler, which makes no sense.  You need to review *variable scope*.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, your HTML and JS will be something like this.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Learning functions and forms</h1>
    <form id="make-average">
      <label for="average">Give me first number</label>
      <input type="text" name="user-entry" 
       id="user-entry-1" placeholder="e.g., 3">
      <label for="average">Give me second number</label>
      <input type="text" name="user-entry" id="user-entry-2" placeholder="e.g., 3">
      <input type="submit" id="additems">
      <br><br>
      <div id="show-result">  </div>
    </form
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
  function displayAverage(average) {
    $("#show-result").html(average);
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#make-average").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var firstNumber = $("#user-entry-1").val();
      var secondNumber = $("#user-entry-2").val();
      var average = (firstNumber + secondNumber) / 2;
      displayAverage(average);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Also, you need to read a little more about both JavaScript and jQuery.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Register form submit event in document on-load to calculate the average.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#make-average").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var firstNumber = $("#user-entry-1").val();
        var secondNumber = $("#user-entry-2").val();
        var average = (parseInt(firstNumber) + parseInt(secondNumber)) / 2; //Use parseFloat if you enter decimal numbers in input fields.
        $("#show-result").html(average);
    });
})
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="make-average">
    <label for="average">Give me first number</label>
    <input type="text" name="user-entry" id="user-entry-1" placeholder="e.g., 3">
    <label for="average">Give me second number</label>
    <input type="text" name="user-entry" id="user-entry-2" placeholder="e.g., 3">
    <input type="submit" id="additems">
    <br><br>
    <div id="show-result"> </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. it helped me modify my own code and make it work. My take away is that you need to use parseInt

Answer (score 0):

it works

```js
function makeAverage() {
 var firstNumber = $("#user-entry-1").val();
 var secondNumber = $("#user-entry-2").val();
      
 var average = (parseInt(firstNumber) + parseInt(secondNumber)) / 2;
  console.log(average);
 return average;
}


function displayAverage(avg) {
$("#show-result").text(avg);
  console.log('avg '+avg);

};
$('form#make-average').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var avg=makeAverage();
  displayAverage(avg);
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 <form id="make-average">
            <label for="average">Give me first number</label>
            <input type="text" name="user-entry" 
            id="user-entry-1" placeholder="e.g., 3">
            <label for="average">Give me second number</label>
            <input type="text" name="user-entry" id="user-entry-2" placeholder="e.g., 3">
            <input type="submit" id="additems">
            <br><br>
 <div id="show-result">  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#additems").click(function() {

var firstNumber = $("#user-entry-1").val();
  var secondNumber = $("#user-entry-2").val();
 var average = makeAverage(firstNumber,secondNumber);
  $("#show-result").html(average);
  alert(average);

});


makeAverage = function(firstNubmer, secondNumber) {

  var fn = parseInt(firstNubmer);
  var sn = parseInt(secondNumber);
  var average = (fn + sn) / 2;
  return average;

}
```

And include jQuery cdn in your html head tag

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#make-average").on('submit',function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();   
        var firstNumber = parseInt($("#user-entry-1").val());
        var secondNumber = parseInt($("#user-entry-2").val());    
        var average = (firstNumber + secondNumber)/2 ;    
        $("#show-result").html(average);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Learning functions and forms</h1>
      <form id="make-average" action="" method="GET" onsubmit="return false;">
            <label for="average">Give me first number</label>
            <input type="text" name="user-entry-1" 
             id="user-entry-1" placeholder="e.g., 3">
            <label for="average">Give me second number</label>
            <input type="text" name="user-entry-2" id="user-entry-2" placeholder="e.g., 3">
            <input type="submit" id="additems">
        </form>
        <br><br>
        <div id="show-result">  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```